# Hamiltonian 4-regular graphs of even order

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, hamiltonicity

All graphs to be considered are simple.  A graph is matching covered if every edge of the graph belongs to a perfect matching of the graph.  A graph is class 1 if it is edge 4-colorable.  A graph is Hamiltonian if it has a circuit containing all its vertices.  A graph is 4-regular if all its vertices have degree 4. A graph is of even order if it has an even number of vertices

I have the following question:

> **Question 1** Is a 4-regular, Hamiltonian graph of even order matching covered necessarily?  Is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:

[image]

We've got a $4$-regular, Hamiltonian graph on $12$ vertices. However, deleting the highlighted edge leaves two components on $5$ vertices, which don't have a perfect matching, so the highlighted edge is not part of any matching.

Comment: Thank you again!